# CSS left and right text stop drop down when they collide.

Tags: html, css

I have a link intense website and I have link on both the right and left when someone makes the browser smaller and the link collide the one on the right goes below the one on the left. How can I get the one on the right to just stop moving when it get closer to the one on the left. attached is a basic example.

[link](http://css-tricks.com/examples/leftandright/)

Comment: Have you tried adding padding?

Comment: I really didn't think it would be this difficult to solve. It's driving me nuts!

Comment: possible duplicate of [hyperlinks stop moving at a specific point when browser is resized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369454/hyperlinks-stop-moving-at-a-specific-point-when-browser-is-resized)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `min-width` on the container will prevent the links from wrap. Based on the example:

```
#textbox {
    min-width: 270px; /* adjust to the needed width */
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it still allows the text on the right to drop below the text left. the link is my site i'm trying to work this out on. It's the email like on the left, see what happens when you move the browser size smaller from the right  [link](ernsteverything.com/ojk